# Facebook iso sdk increases the app size

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, xcode5

I've integrated the latest iOS facebook SDK (v3.10). I did drag and drop the FacebookSDK.framework into my project and unselect the Copy; now the .ipa file size has increased around 8MB. (ipa with FBSDK = 9.9MB -- without FBSDK = 1.5MB)

I tried their sample code, and did the same thing!! But there is no significant changes on the final ipa file!

What would be the possible issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no issue. The Facebook iOS framework is *just that big*. It's big because it's a FAT binary including armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386 and x86_64 architectures.

[image: Screenshot showing Facebook SDK filesize]

```
~ $ lipo -i ./FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/FacebookSDK
Architectures in the fat file: ./FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/FacebookSDK are:
i386 armv7 armv7s x86_64 arm64
```

It also contains 1.1MB of images, but the majority of the size is the FAT binary.

You can probably modify the Xcode project to make it not build for the Simulator (x86_64 and i386). But your app probably runs on 4S+, so you'll need to keep armv7, armv7s and arm64.

Unselecting the copy doesn't change much (except maybe the images bundle won't be added to your resources, so no images will show, you don't want that). The file size still increases because your app links the Facebook SDK binary in with its own binary (that's how it is able to use the Facebook code from the SDK).